# Doctrine2 assosiation in symfony2 manytomany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a problem, using symfony2, doctrine

first my models and relationships:

tables:

```
1.company (has many employements, has many projects)
2.user (has many employements)
3.project (has one company)
4.employement (has one user, has one company)
```

(I know about the possibility ManyToMany between user<->company, but i go with an extra model for employement for other reasons)

The Issue: an the projects/index page, i want to show all projects, from all companies, where this user is employed, ordered by created at. As you can see a user can be employed in more companies at the same time.

In my controller i get all projects like this:

```
$projects = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Projects')
    ->findAll();
```

I Guess the solution could be:

find employements by user

find companies by that employements

get projects by that companies...

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems right, but you will probably need to create a custom repository class with joins to explicitly tell Doctrine to fetch relations (without proxy).

See [Databases and Doctrine (The Symfony Book)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) and [Doctrine Query Language — Doctrine 2 #joins](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)

Example :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class EmployementRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findWithJoins($user) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
        $qb->leftJoin('e.company', 'e')
            ->addSelect('e')
            ->where('e.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResults();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Laurent!
your solution gives me just number of employements by the user.
how can I get all projects by those employements ?

Comment: Once you get all employements with the repository method, you can iterate on them and use something like `getCompanies()`, and then iterate on companies and use `getProjects()`.